# Wordpress docker container to Azure pipelines?

Tags: wordpress, docker, azure-pipelines

I currently have wordpress running inside a docker container but I have to setup an Azure pipeline for my school project but I have no idea how. When checking the Azure site (after clicking setup Pipeline) I have to choose between Azure Repos Git, Bitbucket Cloud, GitHub or other Git but I have no idea how I would commit all the Wordpress files to a github for example..

Could anyone explain how I would setup a pipeline for this project? Or even how I could commit all the wordpress files to a github repository?

Comment: May I know what's the status of this before the weekend? Any puzzle still exists on below suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Before you can create pipeline for you wordpress project, you must host your project into one repository. Only this, our pipeline system can checkout the source code to do next build or release.

For which repos is beeter, this depend on your interests. Just want to let you know that, until now, we provided the full tasks and configuration support to `Azure Repos` and `Github repos`. So, I much recommend you can consider to host your project to one of these two repos.

**Scenario 1**:

If what's your choice is **hosting the project to Github**,

1) Read this [doc](https://help.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line) firstly and follow mentioned steps to finish codes **push**.

2) Then locate to `Azure devops` => `Project settings` => `Service connections` => `New Service Connection` => `Github` => Change `authentication method` to `Personal Access Token`. Input the PAT token which generated from [here](https://github.com/settings/tokens), and **verify** it.

Save it after your provide the `Service connection name` to it.

3) Now, you can go **Pipelines** panel to configure your first pipeline.

Since you are very new to Azure devops, please use `Classic editor` mode to configure your pipeline after you click on the `New pipeline` button. For `YAML` mode, it is a challenge when you does not get very familiar to pipeline:

[image]

4) Select `Github` when it needs you select a source. At this time, you can choose the service connection you created in previous step.

5) Choose corresponding `Repository` and the `Branch`. Then **Continue** => **Empty job**.

[image]

Read this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) and this [blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/deploying-wordpress-application-using-vsts-and-azure-part-one/) to get further familiarization.

---

**Scenario 2:**

If the project hosted at Azure devops Repository, similar with Github, follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/share-your-code-in-git-cmdline?view=azure-devops) to finish the code push.

Then you can ignore the step 2-5 that github used. Just directly select the `Project`, `Repository` and the `Branch`, and **Continue** => **Empty job**.

Now, keep same way with github. Refer to this [blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/deploying-wordpress-application-using-vsts-and-azure-part-one/) to know how to build wordpress project in Azure devops.